# Grouping dates by week in an Excel pivot table which has distinct count

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

My raw data looks like this: [raw_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbSIM.jpg)

I want to group the dates by week, showing the number of distinct shows viewed by each viewer every week.
The data should look like this. [ExpectedOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxRzD.jpg)

I've created a pivot table of my raw data, which looks like this: [Pivot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXjUI.jpg)

When creating the pivot table, I selected 'Add this data to the data model' because I want a distinct count of shows viewed, and that is the only way to make the distinct count option available. Unfortunately, selecting the data model options limits the available grouping options as you cannot group by week.The number of days and start and end date in the grouping pop-up window are grayed out.

So, I tried to create a pivot of my pivot, without adding the data to the data model to see if that would work but it didn't, as the column headers are not dates, so the grouping function is disabled.

I'm really stuck on this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Week is not an option in the grouping box with or without using the Data Model. So I recommend you create a column to calculate the week text in the format you want:

```
=TEXT(B2-WEEKDAY(B2,2)+1,"dd/mm/yy")&" - "&TEXT(B2-WEEKDAY(B2,2)+7,"dd/mm/yy")
```

Then use the data model to allow distinct count:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much. :)